# ExpandableListtView and icons

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i tried to insert icons on the right in the group rows of the expandableListView. I tried with setGroupIndicator but it just replaces the icon on the left. In my case i just want to add an icon on the right of the text of the group rows.. Hou should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the layout you are inflating in the groupView. Use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grouptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/groupicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```